# How deploy an aplication inside drupal

Tags: multi-sites, configuration

I developed a site in *Php* using *Laravel 4*. This site will show many articles and images, that´s why I start to use *Drupal 7*  for present those,  but the problem is that  I cant't found how manage only one drupal site and one sub directory for the application inside it.

I had seek but only found how use many sites but all using drupal, and include modules too, but no applications. Could someone help me please ?

Thanks.

The site is only one and  it is developed in *Laravel 4* but I want to use the features of the *Drupal* for add content and images, post, user management etc.

But *Laravel* manage routes and *ORM* to access the database and easy to integrate with *bootstrap*. That's why I used *Laravel* to develop the aplications.
So to add content I want to use *drupal*.

I have a directory as:

```
HTDOCS

    Aplication

    Drupal
```

But I want to has someone like this;

```
 HTDOCS
   Drupal/Aplication
```

Thanks.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.BolsaGame.com 
   DocumentRoot "C:/Servidor WEB/www/Drupal"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please watch out for mistakes in your question, also give us more details about the directory structure and your environment (Apache/IIS) and its configuration (vhosts).

Comment: I'm having a hard time to understand your question. You developed a site using Laravel 4, so you need Drupal for what? Could you please be more specific?